# Refactoring code duplication so the same textArea is not used in 4 different classes

Tags: java, swing

Looking for the best way to do this. 
Currently in 4 different classes I have:

```
textArea = new JTextArea(10, 55) {
    {
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(i == lineIndex) 
                g.setColor(Color.black);          
                g.drawRect(0, 20, 750, 20);
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
};
```

I've simplified down what I actually have. 
As you can see there is duplication. The only data that is different is what is in the `list`.
A list is passed into each of these classes
There are some other stuff in the class which depends on the textarea and the `lineIndex` variable changes in the class depending on what the user does. I call the repaint() method of the textarea when I need the textarea to draw something else. The paintcomponent does a simple draw.

I'm not sure of the best way for each of the classes to contain the textarea so I dont have duplication. In each of the classes I have an addList(List list) method which the textareas need to use.

Hope I explained this ok.

Thanks

Comment: Might help to have a little bit more of the code, but at the moment I don't see any reason you need to pass the list in (unless it changes size... with is problematic).  Why not pass in the _size_ - immediate code reuse...

Comment: The content of each list is slightly different. I'm not sure what other code to put in. Maybe I could have a method in each class. Something like addTextAreaAndList(TextArea ta, List l)

Comment: I'm assuming the contents of the list were different.  You haven't included any code where that's relevant or referenced, though.  Yes, you reference the size, but unless I see something different, there's no reason you can't pass in the integer index, and avoid the whole loop anyways.  Also, you probably want to move that call to `super.paintComponent()` to _before_ you paint the rectangle, as otherwise your painting will be 'behind' whatever the `super` call draws.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write your own class:

```
class MyTextArea extends JTextArea{

    private final List<Foo> list;

    MyTextArea(int row, int col, List<Foo> list) {
        super(row, col); 
        this.list = list;
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(i == lineIndex) 
                g.setColor(Color.black);          
            g.drawRect(0, 20, 750, 20);
            //use list...
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```